# Issues with TomEE on Amazon AWS EC2 Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, tomcat, java

I've recently tried to run a tomee server on AWS EC2 Linux and ran into Address already in use issues for my port, even though the port is not in use when I try to start the server.

And I were unable to find any solution to this via google etc, and wonder if anyone ever was able to successfully run a TomEE server on amazon's aws ec2 linux or if tomee even runs on ec2.

Specificly my issue is:

when I try to start a Tomee Server on AWS EC2 Linux (t2.micro). it always throws

```
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-5000"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed) <null>:5000
```

Most devs on stack or aws forums suggest to change the port, which I did on the tomee Server.xml . I am 100% sure that the port is free on startup, but somehow it still throws this exception. Also tried to add address="0.0.0.0" to the tag in Server.xml which also didn't help.

Comment: So, if you run "lsof -i tcp:5000", you get nothing?

Comment: i were using netstat to check for the port, and i didn't get anything

Comment: Do you mind trying the lsof?

Comment: It's been a while since we dropped TomEE in favour of Tomcat, but I had a look at my installation notes: I had to disable IPv6, and remove the IPv6 localhost from the /etc/hosts, otherwise  Java was trying to connect to  ::1 while TomEE was only listening on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille i tried lsof and it doesn't Show anything for my port, i tried to removed the line with the ipv6 hosts but still the same issue

Comment: Would you mind adding your server.xml to your question?

Comment: No need to be ashamed.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille it was just the Default Server.xml where I tried to Change the <connector port.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I've now tried my webapp with wildfly since tomee had so many issues, and widlfly seems to work fine